# How can I use EJS to, after I insert the data on the EJS file, create a HTML and save it locally?

Tags: html, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, ejs, server-side-rendering

That is the flow I want:

1 - Have a normal HTML file on one folder (HTML folder)

2 - Take this file, convert is to EJS file

3 - Insert the data I want on the EJS file

4 - Convert that EJS file back to HTML file, so now I will have the "same" HTML file, but now with all the data I want.

5 - Store this HTML on AWS S3 ( Or just locally, for now )

Answer (score 0):

#### Render an EJS file into HTML markup

<sup>Source: [Render EJS File with Node.js](https://www.devextent.com/ejs-render-file/)</sup>

[EJS](https://ejs.co/) is a templating language that uses JavaScript to generate HTML. This post will illustrate how to use Node.js with TypeScript to render an EJS file into HTML markup. Please  make sure you have [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and [npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm) installed first. If you are unfamiliar with Typescript please read my post describing how to [compile TypeScript with npm](https://www.devextent.com/npm-compile-typescript/).

#### EJS

Begin by creating a new EJS file named index.ejs. This file will be the  template used to generate index.html. If the model is passed into the  template it will render the content as a paragraph.

```js
<!-- Sample Page -->

<h1>Sample Page</h1>

<% if (model) { %>
  <%= model.content %>
<% } %>
```

#### package.json

If you don't already have a package.json created you can create one by running the command npm init and following the prompts.

You will need your package.json to include these packages:

```json
{
  "name": "package-name-goes-here",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/ejs": "^2.6.2",
    "@types/node": "^11.9.4",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3333"
  }
}
```

You can also copy the devDependencies section and run the command `npm install` instead of installing one at a time.

#### Node.js

Create a new TypeScript file named render.ts. Then add the following code to import the modules that we will use.

```
//imports
import util = require("util");
import fs = require("fs");
import ejs = require("ejs");
//promisify
const mkdir = util.promisify(fs.mkdir);
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
```

The first import is the [util](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html) module so that we can use the [promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) function. Then import the [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html) module for file system access. Before using three of the functions from the fs module we can promisify them allowing for the use of async/await instead of nested callbacks. The last is for EJS, and since the render  file function returns a promise by default we do not need to use  promisify.

Below the import statements add an async function named render. This is where the HTML output will be generated and written to a file named index.html. It needs to be marked as an async function so  that the keyword await can be used. Then make sure to call the function  so the code that is about to be added will execute.

```js
async function render() {
  try {
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
render();
```

Before rendering our EJS file we will need a folder to put the output. So add the following to our render function:

```js
await mkdir("dist", { recursive: true });
```

This will create a new directory named dist where the html output will be saved. By passing the recursive property we can  ensure parent folders are created even if none are necessary. After  creating the dist folder we can use EJS to render the index.ejs template to HTML. The resulting HTML string is then written to a file named  index.html in the dist folder.

At this point your index.ts file should look like this:

```
//imports
import util = require("util");
import fs = require("fs");
import ejs = require("ejs");
//promisify
const mkdir = util.promisify(fs.mkdir);
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
async function render() {
  try {
    //create output directory
    await mkdir("dist", { recursive: true });

    //render ejs template to html string
    const html = await ejs
      .renderFile("index.ejs", { model: false })
      .then((output) => output);
    //create file and write html
    await writeFile("dist/index.html", html, "utf8");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
render();
```

In order to run this script we need to add a  tsconfig.json file to configure the TypeScript compiler. This will  compile the TypeScript into JavaScript so that it can be used by  node.js. Add the tsconfig file to the same folder as the render.js  script.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": ["render.js"]
}
```

We also need to add a script to the package.json file  created earlier. This script will compile render.ts and then run it  using node. Your package.json should look like this:

```json
{
  "name": "package-name-goes-here",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "render": "tsc && node dist/render.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/ejs": "^2.6.2",
    "@types/node": "^11.9.4",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3333"
  }
}
```

#### EJS render HTML

The render script can be run in a terminal window by typing the command npm run render. Make sure to run this command from the directory where your  package.json is located. After running the render script you should now  see a folder named dist containing a file named index.html.

The contents of index.html should look like this:

```
Sample Page
```

Notice that the conditional block containing the model  content, in the index.ejs template, is not included in the html output. This is because in the render script the model was passed in as false. Now we'll create an object to pass in as the model with some sample  content to the sample page.

In the render.ts file previously  created, after the import statements, create an object and add a  property to it called content with the value set to a sample of content.

```
const pageModel = {
  content: "This is some sample content. Located on the sample page.",
};
```

Then pass this object in to the ejs.renderFile function instead of false. The render.ts file should look like this:

```
//imports
import util = require("util");
import fs = require("fs");
import ejs = require("ejs");
//promisify
const mkdir = util.promisify(fs.mkdir);
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);

const pageModel = {
  content: "<p>This is some sample content. Located on the sample page.</p>",
};
async function render() {
  try {
    //create output directory
    await mkdir("dist", { recursive: true });

    //render ejs template to html string
    //pass pageModel in to render content
    const html = await ejs
      .renderFile("index.ejs", { model: pageModel })
      .then((output) => output);
    //create file and write html
    await writeFile("dist/index.html", html, "utf8");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
render();
```

With the model object passed into the template we should now see the conditional block rendered in the index.html output file.  Run the command npm run render once more.

The index.html file in the dist folder should now look like this:

```
<h1>Sample Page</h1>
<p>This is some sample content. Located on the sample page.</p>
```

The index.ejs template can now render dynamic HTML  content according to the model object configured in the render.ts file  and by running npm run render after each change to generate an updated index.html file.